# Несовместимость версии pip и tensorflow

Tags: python, pip, tensorflow

При попытке установить tensorflow `pip install tensorflow` 
Пишет

`Collecting tensorflow
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.`

При попытке обновить pip пишет, что и так установлена последняя версия (18.1)
`Requirement already up-to-date: pip in e:\projects\python\Project1\venv\lib\site-packages (18.1)`

Установлен только python 3.7.0. Система windows 7 x64.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас установлены Python 3 и Python 2. Используйте `python2 -m pip install --upgrade pip` или `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`. И соответственно `pip2 install tensorflow` или `pip3 install tensorflow`

Comment: Назовите точную версию вашей операционной системы, разрядность процессора и ОС и версию питона. И на всякий случай не помешает скриншот с этим pip install (там деталей будет видно больше). Вполне вероятно, что для вашей системы заранее скомпилированного tensorflow просто нет. (Совместимость с pip, естественно, абсолютно ни при чём)

Comment: Ну вот, tensorflow не собран для питона 3.7. Или собирайте из исходников как-то вручную, или ставьте питон 3.6

Comment: спасибо, попробую установить на 3.6

Comment: И не путайте версии pip. У вас их два: один системный за пределами PyCharm (версия 10) и второй внутри виртуального окружения в PyCharm-проекте (версия 18). Если уж вы используете PyCharm, то не надо писать никаких pip install в терминале самостоятельно

Comment: Ну или использовать pip из терминала может и можно, но тогда его нужно запускать в виртуальном окружении вашего проекта, то есть `venv\Scripts\pip`

Comment: Тогда может быть стоит удалить системный pip, если я пользуюсь только pycharm?
Спасибо

Comment: Не стоит, пригодится ещё, просто не используйте его

Comment: Вообще, поддержку питона 3.7 в tensorflow ещё никак не завезли. Сделить за изменениями на эту тему можно тут: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20517